# What can the macros below be used for?

Tags: c, macros

```
#define MEMCACHED_COMMAND_GET(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
#define MEMCACHED_COMMAND_GET_ENABLED() (0)
```

The macros above seems totally useless ,what can they be used for??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is probably several definitions for those macros, and you will pick one or another depending on a compilation flag.
This enable for instance debug information to be provided only when built in debug mode.

For instance, in `memcached_dtrace.h`, there is something like:

```
#if ENABLE_DTRACE
...
#define MEMCACHED_COMMAND_GET(arg0, arg1, arg2) \
    __dtrace_memcached___command__get(arg0, arg1, arg2)
#define MEMCACHED_COMMAND_GET_ENABLED() \
    __dtraceenabled_memcached___command__get()
...
#else
...
#define MEMCACHED_COMMAND_GET(arg0, arg1, arg2)
#define MEMCACHED_COMMAND_GET_ENABLED() (0)
...
#endif
```

Those commands only do something when `ENABLE_DTRACE` is activated at build time.

Comment: Empty macros expand to empty lines, which are compiled into nothing. It's also a popular way to include log messages in code by defining a `LOG` macro as an alias of `fprintf` when you compile with debugging flags enabled, or have it expand to nothing when debugging flags are disabled. Voila, no debug messages and no slowdown at runtime to determine whether to print them.

Comment: [`assert()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/assert.h.html) is another common example of this sort of behavior.